# Is there a puppet module to manage policykit rule on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: puppet

Is there any module which could help to manage policykit rules on puppet for Ubuntu 16.04 instead of putting file on /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [there is](https://forge.puppet.com/jhoblitt/policykit/readme). For future reference, the best place to look for puppet modules generally is to search [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppet.com). That is the central repository for modules and any module uploaded there can be installed using puppet by typing:

```
puppet module install jhoblitt-policykit
```

But obviously, you will want to update the name of the module to be whatever you want to install.